# A few words in a coloured/grey background box

Tags: color, boxes, highlighting

How can I write a few words with a grey highlighting box in the background, as shown in the picture below ("TEXT 4")?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have up to now?

Comment: I reworded your question a bit, since you didn't seem to be looking for a solution for the rest of the picture at all. Focused on the highlighting, as it is now, it's a better fit for our "one feature" question style. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @doncherry No problem. Its absolutely fine :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

put the xcolor package in the preamble,

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

then use a command like this:

```
\fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{TEXT}
```

Change 'gray' to the shade that suits your gods liking.

Comment: No Problemo. Any time.

Comment: Seen many solutions around. This is so delightfully simple!